# Why is oxalic acid more acidic than benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, resonance

I came across this fact while reading my book and was confused. Looking at the structures, I had the intuition that benzoic acid would be more acidic as the conjugate base formed will resonate all over the benzene ring.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Compare the induction effect of phenyl and carboxyl.

Comment: "the conjugate base will resonate all over the benzene ring"- Its not necessarily a good thing. Charge instead of resonating completely with a more electronegative oxygen is also being shared with carbon which doesn't handle it that well making it less stable.